# Increasing internet explorer timeout in html / php

Tags: php, html, facebook, internet-explorer, connection-timeout

I wrote a simple facebook application using php. The application loading time is more than the allowed time in internet explorer (Works fine in chrome and firefox).

There is no possibility of decreasing the loading time.

Can I do it by HTML tags or PHP Code ?

Comment: sincerely "is not possible to decrease the loading time"... is an answer that I will never heard...

Comment: does your script hit the PHP timeout or IEs waiting on content? Did you increase PHPs timeout?

Comment: I'm not sure i understood how exactly I need to change the header. For example I have the following php code:
<html>
<?php
echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {

echo $i."
"; sleep(1); }

echo date('h:i:s') . "\n";

?>
</html>

this code doesn't run on Internet Explorer because it takes 8 seconds for timeout.

How do I run this code in internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

There ain't no HTML tag you can use, your best bet would be a sending a http header with a long [keep-alive](http://www.http-stats.com/Keep-Alive).

Comment: "the field is not supported by any known client"

Comment: @fingerman: This currently is the only protocol-way you can do this, regardless of clients supporting it or not.

Answer (score -1):

Hey, It's a problem with your IE setup, default time out for IE is 60 seconds... see this rendering (IN IE) of your script (Wamp Server):

```
05:21:20
0<BR>1<BR>2<BR>3<BR>4<BR>5<BR>6<BR>7<BR>8<BR>9<BR>10<BR>11<BR>12<BR>13<BR>14<BR>15<BR>16<BR>17<BR>18<BR>19<BR>20<BR>21<BR>22<BR>23<BR>24<BR>25<BR>26<BR>27<BR>28<BR>29<BR>30<BR>31<BR>32<BR>33<BR>34<BR>35<BR>36<BR>37<BR>38<BR>39<BR>40<BR>41<BR>42<BR>43<BR>44<BR>45<BR>46<BR>47<BR>48<BR>49<BR>50<BR>51<BR>52<BR>53<BR>54<BR>55<BR>56<BR>57<BR>58<BR>59<BR><br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded in <b>Somewhereovertherainbow</b> on line <b>9</b><br />
```

as you see, the limiting factor in my case is php timeout (which can be changed, if I want to) not an IE limit...

maybe you messed around with your registry?

Comment: -1 I don't think it would be a good idea to mess with the clients registry in an online app. (let alone the possibility)

Comment: It's not the client's registry, it's his testing computer registry.... IE out of the box supports 60 seconds time out. so i asked if he messed around with his registry (past tense)...

Comment: Who said that the loading time is less than a minute?

Comment: the loading time is less than 60 seconds. I tried to run my code on wamp server locally and it worked. are there any settings i need to change in GoDaddy to fix my problem?